# Блок кода рассчитан на неполное число строк

Tags: дефект, статус-отклонено, дизайн

В [вопросе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/522256/178988) есть код на 38 строк. И у блока кода есть вертикальный скролл. Неужели эти несколько пикселей действительно следует скроллить?

Возможно, стоит настроить максимальную высоту так, чтобы помещалось целое число строк?

[image: Скролл не прокручен]

[image: Скролл прокручен до конца]

Comment: А у меня ровно 36 строк входит. FF 46.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Наполовину отображённая строка — это хороший индикатор в дополнению к скролл-бару, что отображается не весь код. Конечно, в том единственном случае, когда частично отображённая строка — последняя, получается несколько некрасиво, но это редкий случай. Кроме того, при наличии горизонтального скролла определить реальное отображённое пространство не так-то просто.